# How to write the set-builder notation for the "best $n$ elements of the set S"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set $S$ with 100 elements, and a very simple function defined over my set $f : S → [0, 1]$. This function simply tells me how "good" an element is (this function is strictly monotonous).

Now I want to define a subset $G \subset S$, which contains the top 10 best elements in $S$, i.e. those for which $f(x)$ gives the highest 10 values.

How do I write $G$ in short **set-builder notation**?

I had an idea about repeatedly using $\underset{x \in S}{\operatorname{argmin}} ~f(x)$, where $S$ kept shrinking, namely $S_i = S_{i-1} - \{\underset{x \in S}{\operatorname{argmin}}~f(x)\}$, and after 90 iterations, $S_{90}$ would be my "top 10" set. But I have no idea how to write these iterations in set-builder notation.

Comment: Using argmax, you only need 10 steps rather than 90... :)

Comment: Your function $f$ is not necessarily injective? So exactly hos is the subset $G$ defined in case of ties, e.g., if $f$ happens to be a constant function?

Comment: I thought about argmax, but it seemed even more hopeless to write set-builder notation for it. I'd need to write that "$G$ are those elements given by argmax, and then remove it, then apply argmax again, and at the end see what the repeated argmax found in the past". No idea how.

Comment: @bof Let's assume for now that $f$ is bijective. Indeed, you're right, and what you're saying is actually important in my case, but that goes in a future question.

Comment: If $f$ is injective you could use $$G=\{x\in S:|\{y\in S:f(x)\lt f(y)\}|\lt10\}.$$ Of course, if $f$ is not injective, that $G$ could have more than $10$ elements.

Comment: @bof Awesome! And simple. And obvious. To make sure I got it: "$G$ is the set of those $x \in S$ for which there are less than 10 elements $y \in S$ for which $f(y)$ gives a greater result than $f(x)$." Did I read it properly? Please make it an answer so I can upvote and eventually accept it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Note that injectivity of $f$ follows from strict monotonicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a set $S$ with $|S|\ge10$ and a function $f:S\to\mathbb R,$ the set
$$G=\{x\in S:|\{y\in S:f(x)\lt f(y)\}|\lt10\}$$
consists of the "best" $10$ elements of $S,$ including all elements *tied* for one of the top ten places. (Elements with greater $f$-values are considered "better".)